# Toggle two checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, toggle

I have two checkboxes, each handling a vertical and horizontal state respectively. It is ok if both are off, but if one is on the other must be off and most importantly both can not be on.

I do not want to jQuery here.

If I both are unchecked and I hit the horizontal one and then the vertical, they will toggle, as the horizontal goes unchecked and the vertical will become checked.

But if I do it the other way starting with the vertical, I can't check the horizontal.

Full code is on [github](https://github.com/shanegibney/Scale-Canvas-Upload-Image-Dimensions) and demo running on [gh-pages](https://shanegibney.github.io/Scale-Canvas-Upload-Image-Dimensions/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Toggle</title>
</head>
<style>
  .constraint {
    color: #007bff;
    padding: 0rem .5rem;
  }
  
  span.horz:before {
    content: "\2194";
  }
  
  span.vert:before {
    content: "\2195";
  }
</style>

<body>
  <span class="constraint">Constraint: </span>
  <span class="constraint vert">
        <input type="checkbox" id="vertical" onchange="constraints()">
        <span class="constraint horz"></span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="horizontal" onchange="constraints()">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function constraints() {
    inputVert = document.getElementById("vertical");
    inputHorz = document.getElementById("horizontal");
    console.log("initially: vert:" + inputVert.checked);
    console.log("initially: horz:" + inputHorz.checked);
    if (inputVert.checked) {
      console.log("vert clicked -> vert:" + inputVert.checked);
      console.log("vert clicked -> horz:" + inputHorz.checked);
      // inputHorz = document.getElementById("horizontal");
      inputHorz.checked = false;
      // inputVert.checked = true;
    };
    if (inputHorz.checked) {
      console.log("horz clicked -> vert:" + inputVert.checked);
      console.log("horz clicked -> horz:" + inputHorz.checked);
      // inputVert = document.getElementById("vertical");
      inputVert.checked = false;
      // inputHorz.checked = true;
    };
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Any help greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JQuery you can do it like this, hope this help you

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Toggle</title>
</head>
<style>
  .constraint {
    color: #007bff;
    padding: 0rem .5rem;
  }

  span.horz:before {
    content: "\2194";
  }

  span.vert:before {
    content: "\2195";
  }
</style>

<body>
  <span class="constraint">Constraint: </span>
  <span class="constraint vert">
  <input type="checkbox" id="vertical">
  <span class="constraint horz"></span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="horizontal">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
    $('#vertical').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
          $('#horizontal').attr('checked', false);
        }    
    });
    
    $('#horizontal').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
          $('#vertical').attr('checked', false);
        }    
    });
  
  
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Should the JS be inside an immediately invoked function? Or could the use already of an IIF cause the JS you wrote not to run?

Comment: I have added the jQuery cdn link inside the head.

Comment: Having trouble getting this into the main project, which is on github herehttps://github.com/shanegibney/Scale-Canvas-Upload-Image-Dimensions and a gh-pages demo here https://shanegibney.github.io/Scale-Canvas-Upload-Image-Dimensions/

Comment: also now i see you are including jquery in head and jquery slim at the bottom, let one of them only and try again

Comment: tested: if you remove the line that include jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js file at the bottom, all work normally

Comment: Removed the jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js from the bottom and it works now thanks for looking at that, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

### Use radio buttons

This is a classic scenario for using an input radio. It only allows for one to be selected at a time:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="fav_language" value="HTML"> HTML <br>
  <input type="radio" name="fav_language" value="CSS"> CSS<br>
  <input type="radio" name="fav_language" value="JavaScript"> JavaScript
</form>

<p><b>Note:</b> When a user clicks on a radio-button, it becomes checked, and all other radio-buttons with equal name become unchecked.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it allows for none to be check initially, but once one is checked, you cannot go back to the none-checked state. You add another button or control that resets it to the initial none-checked state, or  have another radio button labelled `none` appear the moment something is selected.

Comment: I was hoping to change the checkbox to a nice looking toggle like here http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ But if I have to use radio buttons I don't think I'll be able to do that. Thanks

Comment: Please, put some context around your link. The answer can't rely only on external content, that might go offline, making the post useless to other users...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado fixed. Also added info about its one limitation and how to work around it.

Comment: @ShaneG I'm pretty sure you can use CSS to change the look of a radio button as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Leonardo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46221838/2200913), you can further simplify it to the following:

```
$('#vertical').on("change", function() {
   $('#horizontal').attr('checked', !$(this).is(":checked"));
});
    
$('#horizontal').on("change", function() {
   $('#vertical').attr('checked', !$(this).is(":checked"));
});
```